# How do i make wordpress search ignore a list of words?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a kind of complex wordpress search on my site, with some variables and selects beside the text field, and i want make this search ignore some words if typed on text field, but i dont want use a plugin for that and dont have any idea how to do it.

Someone did this before and can help me?